# How do I find good mining spots?

Tags: rebel-galaxy

I have a mining laser and a fault tracker and want to do some mining. However, most asteroid fields I come across only have worthless Metallic Ore with a few pieces of Obtainium. The only exception was an ice field which had some more vaulable stuff.

How do I find places that have more valuable materials? Is there a way to spot them without having to scan every minable asteroid individually to find out if there is anything valuable in the area?

Comment: Have you tried traveling to more dangerous galaxies/systems?  In general, higher danger = higher reward (true for fighting enemies and running goods).  I haven't tried mining myself so I'm not sure.

Comment: @mmatthews Yeah, I actually found Face of Gozu in the second system and got over 1 million credits in a matter of minutes. But it was just luck I ran into the asteroids accidentally. I was wondering if there is a way to tell by visual or other cues (shape of the asteroid, name of the field etc.) if there is anything valuable nearby, because if I set out to mine, I usually just scan worthless Metallic Ore.

Answer (score 1):

If you find the hackable transmitters flying around, about one in three times they tell you the location of mining spots. I haven't tried to quantify it, but my sense is they are better than the ones you find randomly. You do usually have to fight a few enemies when you arrive.